# use of ば　+ って in a sentence

Tags: sentence, quotes, form

> おかげで６年間俺はずっと後悔してきた
> That to that/Because of that, I dragged my regret for 6 years
>
> あの時ちゃんと返事しとければって
>
> 好きだって
> That I love you.

So the character is saying his friend ghosting him prevent him for answering to her confession, but now they meet again and he's telling her that.

My interpretative is that both って "quoting" his 後悔してきた, however I'm not sure how to take 返事しとければ

Some googling suggest 返事しとければよばった but can just be omitted like that?

Comment: Must be 返事しとければよ**か**った?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the previous verb 後悔する, I'm very sure that [～ばよかった](https://hedgehog-japanese.com/grammar/jlpt-n3/bayokatta/) is intended here.

Although Japanese has a wide variety of idiomatic omission after conditionals, the existence of ～ておく (しとければ < しておければ) makes it doubly certain. Since ～ておく implies that one intentionally sets something in a state to take an effect thereafter, ～ておけばよかった is an especially common expression when someone regrets the past choice at a turning point of life.